# Query exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Exception: Timeout expired

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a worker that runs a delete query on a table where it's deleting about 5,000 records and the query sometimes generates a timeout exception. This is what the code looks like:

```
var TheReordsToDeleteInDB = (from c in MyDC.SomeTable
                             where c.UserID == TheUserID
                             select c);

if (TheDemoLeadCallHistoriesInDB.Any() == true) {
        MyDC.SomeTable.DeleteAllOnSubmit(TheReordsToDeleteInDB );
        MyDC.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I've looked at other answers on this bug and locks aren't the issue. Why does this query only timeout randomly and is there a better way to write this delete query?

Comment: I'm sure you will be helped with this specific problem but it would be a good move to read through some query tuning tutorials to see how it'd one in general.

Comment: Perhaps do it in batches. Sounds like you are hitting a command timeout.

Comment: Try to set command timeout 0, in your case MyDC.CommandTimeout=0; before query execution.